# Difficulty declaring that user input is not an integer C#

Tags: c#, variables, integer, declare

I could use a try catch scenario here, but I'm used to saying if x = 30 or if x > 100, but what I need to say is if x != int, but I am not allowed to use that statement.

What I need is a way to say, if the input by the user does not equal an integer then...

```
      Console.Write("Enter number of cats:"); //cats are 121.45

     var temp = Console.ReadLine();
     int cats;
     if (int.TryParse(temp, out cats))
   {

      price = (cats* 121.45);
   }
  else
 {
    Console.Write{"Number of cats must be an integer. Please enter an integer")
 }


      Console.Write ("Enter number of dogs"); //dogs are 113.35
      int product2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
      price2 = (dogs * 113.35);
      Console.Write ("Enter number of mice:"); //mice are 23.45
      int mice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
      price3= (mice * 23.45);
      Console.Write("Enter number of turtles:"); //turtles are 65.00
      int turtles = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
      price4 = (turtles * 65.00);
      Console.Write("Total price : $");
      grosssales = price1 + price2 + price3 + price4; //PRICE ONE IS NOT RECOGNIZED?
      Console.WriteLine(grosssales);
      Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: What's the point of deleting your entire question and replacing it with `nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn`?

Answer (score 4):

```
var temp = Console.ReadLine();
int cats;
if (int.TryParse(temp, out cats))
{
    // Yay, got the int.
}
else
{
    // Boooo, error.  Do something here to handle it.
}
```

[`.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx) is your friend.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [int.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx) to establish if user input can be parsed as an int.

```
  var userInput = Console.ReadLine();     
  int cats;
  if(!int.TryParse(userInput, out cats))
  {
      //userInput could not be parsed as an int
  }
  else
  {
      //cats is good
  }
```

Comment: I'm not a huge fan of if(!... Cleaner to invert the if statement.

Comment: @JohanLarsson I usually end up doing things this way to reduce nesting (i.e. the bad case would most likely return or continue a loop) and then have no `else`. Of course, Dyjkstra wouldn't approve because using this style leads to multiple exit points. I don't really care though!

Comment: This does what I would like it to do, but the variable price becomes unrecognized in later parts of the code when it was recognized before replacing the code.

Comment: There's no `price` in my code, so we can only guess at your implementation. Why not update your question with more code?

Comment: @user1513637 If you declare price as an int then there is no reason for it not to become recognised later on. Is the variable still in scope at that stage?

Comment: It is still in scope. All of the code has been updated.

Answer (score 0):

Use `TryParse`:

```
int cats;
if (Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine(), out cats)) {
  price = cats * 239.99;
  // go on here
} else {
  Console.WriteLine("The number of cats must be an integer.");
}
```